# Why pyplot imshow doesn't match its colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

[image: imshow colorbar issue]

The question is: how can the different values (0 and 255) be depicted with the same black color? And also the same values (255) are shown in black and white?

My code is below:

```
 #Vizualizing grayscale
def visualize_input(img,ax):
   pos=ax.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
   width,height=img.shape
   #thresh = img.max()
   for x in range (width):
    for y in range(height):
        ax.annotate(str(round(img[x][y],2)), xy=(x,y),
                    horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='center',
                    color='blue') #if img[x][y]<=thresh else 'black')
   plt.colorbar(pos)          

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax=fig.add_subplot()
visualize_input(X_train[0].reshape(28,28),ax)
```

Any help appriciable!

Comment: Well from the look of it it looks like your axes ```x``` and ```y``` are inverted somewhere. Can you try changing  ```xy=(x, y)``` to ```xy=(y, x)``` just to see what it gives?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that due to FOR order i had to set xy=(y,x).